# Putting div's on the same row

Tags: html, css

It's my understanding that to make div's line up on the save row you just need to make sure the `col-sm-#'s` add up to 12.

This isn't working for me, and wherever I place the isCoop section in my code, it ends up beneath the row I want. I just want the isCoop section to appear on the same line as the div's above it in this class.

I've changed the `col-sm-#'s` with no results

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-1 required campaign-drpdwn">
        <select id="campaign" class="form-control font-weight-bold" ng-options="value.key as value.label for value in vm.campaignOptions" ng-model="vm.campaignOption" ng-change="vm.selectCampaignBy()"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 no-padding required-div">*</div>
    <!--<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Campaign Budget</label>-->
    <div class="col-sm-1 input-group" ng-show="!vm.selectCampaign">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.Budget" class="form-control col-sm-2" name="budget" id="txtCampaignBudget" placeholder="enter budget" ng-required="!vm.selectCampaign == true" ng-keydown="vm.KeyPressEvent($event,vm.Budget)" ng-blur="vm.formatNumberWithoutDollar(vm.Budget)">
    </div>
    <span id="budget-lblerror" class="col-sm-offset-1 color-red" ng-show="campaignform.budget.$invalid && (campaignform.budget.$touched || vm.submitted)">Not valid input!</span>
    <-- isCoop section -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="IsCoop" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coop</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.IsCoop" ng-value="1" name="IsCoop" />Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.IsCoop" ng-value="0" name="IsNotCoop" />No
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: The "col-*" class is a "flex-item" class, which means it behaves like that only if the parent or the wrapper is a "flex-container". In case of Bootstrap, it's either the "row" or the "d-flex" class.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into flex-boxes. This will keep you away from all the naming conventions. So your main div where you have class form-group. Add a styling of display:flex. You'll get your result. Make sure that your div that contains form-group has a width of %100.